# I've known you "since after" I met you. This looks so absurd!

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I've encountered these structures today.

> I've known you **since after** I met you in Paris.
> or
> I've worked here **since right/just after** I graduated.

What is it?
Having researched I just can say that some people consider it ok, but why, nobody explains.

Isn't it grammatically incorrect structure? I believe there must be only **"since"**. Like:

> I've known you **since** I met you in Paris.

What do you think of it? 
Can we use **"since after"** or not?

Comment: "since before" sounds acceptable but "since after" is redundant

Comment: @小奥利奥, why acceptable? Can you bring more examples with "since before"?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520203/what-is-since-before-without-anything-between-these-two-words

Answer (score 1):

I can understand why someone might say "I've worked here since just after I graduated", on the grounds that they didn't literally start work the moment they were handed their certificate - although "since I graduated" would be perfectly acceptable.

I suppose it could be argued in a similar way that the two people didn't really 'get to know' one another at their first meeting, but even so "I've known you since after I met you" sounds pretty absurd to me.